# Multiple Firefox Sync accounts

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

How can I set up Firefox on a Windows 7 family PC so that Firefox can be used by people who have a Firefox Sync account as well as those who don't? How can FF Sync be setup so that I can log out of my Sync account when I leave the computer?

This is a computer were I cannot just add other Windows 7 user accounts and I cannot install Google Chrome and use Google Accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Firefox Profile Manager to create multiple profiles.

1. Windows Key + R to open the Run dialog, type **firefox.exe -p** and press Enter.
2. Create your additional profile(s).
3. Create additional shortcuts to these profiles by appending '-p ProfileName' to the shortcut Target: path in the shortcut properties.

Synced profiles can be logged out of by choosing Options, Sync, and the Disconnect button on your Firefox Account. You may need to clear synced data from the profile after disconnecting your account.

More information on setting up Firefox Profiles is at [MakeUseOF](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/firefox-profiles-run-multiple-firefox-profiles/) and [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/209320/how-to-set-up-and-use-multiple-profiles-user-accounts-in-firefox/).

Answer (score 3):

You can go to `about:profiles` and create a new profile. Then *Launch profile in new browser*.

See: [Use the Profile Manager to create and remove Firefox profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles#w_starting-the-profile-manager).